# Opening Page from Quick launch in dialog box

Tags: sharepoint-server

Trying to open a SharePoint 2010 Page in a dialog box from quick launch having ok and cancel buttons in it. How would i do this to achieve it i tried few jquery but not getting the result as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit quick launch and add JavaScript into the URL text field.

```
JavaScript:var options=SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.url='http://url';
options.height = 400;
void(SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options))
```

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/12/sharepoint-opening-2010-dialog-box-from.html

Comment: Hi Amal Hashim I tried it but I don't see quick launch option in my site settings and also there is no Ok and cancle buttons in this modal pop up. is there anything I have to look in for. Thanks

Comment: Enable Publishing feature. After that you will be able to see Navigation under Site Settings page. This is just a pseudo code, you can enhance it with your own code.

Comment: Publishing feature is already activated and when i try to add the javascript in the url it is giving error saying "ensure that the url is valid and begins with either a valid charchter or valid supported protocol "

Comment: It worked after following instructions from here http://www.myspblog.com/2011/04/javascript-quick-launch-top-navigation.html